# Strange inverter PWM output signal at startup

Tags: electrical-engineering, power-electronics

I’m monitoring the output of a 3-phase inverter with an oscilloscope, the inverter is a Siemens Sinamics V20.

I see that when I enable the power output of the inverter, I have a strange sequence before the expected 50Hz sine modulation: for at least 100ms I have a pulsed output with the same polarity (positive or negative).

Oscilloscope screenshot with resistive load:

[image: With load]

Oscilloscope screenshot without load:

[image: Without load]

Why is there this behavior? How can I disable it to start immediately with the sinusoidal modulation?

Comment: Looks like it might be an initial transient prior to some feedback loop states getting where they need to be.  Is this an inverter starting up with load on it? If so, what does it look like without load?

Comment: I added to the question the screenshot for both with and without load.